# Swap the elements in dropdown

Tags: jquery

How to swap the element from dropdown, for e.g when i hover and select second element in dropdown first element show second in place. i am unable to do this. I am using ul li html if other option please let me know.

```js
$('#selectUl li:not(":first")').addClass('unselected');
$('#selectUl').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('li').click(
            function(){
                $('.unselected').removeClass('unselected');
                $(this).siblings('li').addClass('unselected');
    
                var index = $(this).index();
                $('select[name=size]')
                    .find('option:eq(' + index + ')')
                    .attr('selected',true);
     
            });
    },
    function(){
    });
```

```css
ul {
    width: 8em;
    line-height: 2em;
}

li {
    display: list-item;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-width: 0;
    text-indent: 1em;
}
li:first-child {
    border-top-width: 1px;
}

li.unselected {
    display: none;
}
ul#selectUl:hover li,
ul#selectUl:hover li.unselected {
    display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="selectUl">
    <li>small</li>
    <li>large</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example using [.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method, if that is what you mean

```js
$('#selectUl li').click(function(){
  $(this).prependTo('#selectUl');
  $('#selectUl').removeClass('hoverable');
   // escape js event loop and give hoverable class back
  setTimeout(function() {$('#selectUl').addClass('hoverable');}, 1);
});
```

```css
ul {
    width: 8em;
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 2em;
}

li {
    display: list-item;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-width: 0;
    text-indent: 1em;
}
li:first-child {
    border-top-width: 1px;
}

ul#selectUl li { display: none; }
ul#selectUl li:first-child { display: list-item; }
ul#selectUl.hoverable:hover li { display: list-item; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="selectUl" class="hoverable">
    <li>small</li>
    <li>medium</li>
    <li>large</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if i am select dropdown still dropdown open @sojtin

Comment: Yes i want to close dropdown on select?

Comment: @SumanChepuri is the answer correct? If your done please accept this answer